# The best tool for visualizing ontologies?

Tags: visualization, semantics, rdf, ontology, protege

I am looking to visualize ontologies for understanding and making others understand. I would prefer to have top-down hierarchy of classes. I have used `OntoGraph` which comes with `Protégé`, but I am not happy with the figure :(. I have also used `Microsoft Visio` and stencils available for `Ontology`, but that too has not impressed me.

Through this question I would like to know which is the best tool for visualizing an ontology for general purpose, and/or for specific purpose (like writing an academic paper).

Thanks.

~Codera

Comment: There's also http://vowl.visualdataweb.org/webvowl/index.html

Comment: I just ran into this, really cool: http://vowl.visualdataweb.org/webvowl.html

Comment: [OWLGrEd](http://owlgred.lumii.lv/) might be useful. They offer online visualization (don't see any customization options though) and a desktop editor - only for Windows :(

Answer (score 5):

I do not have complete answer for your specific problem, but you may try to review the Mike Bergman's [list of tools](http://www.mkbergman.com/414/large-scale-rdf-graph-visualization-tools/) (for ontology visualization).

Note, RDF is a graph, so you may be able to use any graph-visualization software. "Only" need to map RDF to tool-specific model.

Answer (score 1):

While not an ontology specific tool, [thejit](http://thejit.org/) is a very nice javascript visualization toolkit.  I've used it in the past for custom semweb-related visualizations.  You won't get much out of the box support but if you don't mind putting in some coding time, you can get some nice looking graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend you to utilize the graphical editor of TopBraid Composer Maestro Edition. The graphics are not the most beautiful ones. However, it's interactive ;-)