# Some way to visualize ontology's "supermodel"?

Tags: rdf, visualization, owl, ontology

Given an OWL ontology, are there any tools to visualize **possible** relations between individuals of classes (without having individuals)? There are a lot of tools ([The best tool for visualizing ontologies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409187/the-best-tool-for-visualizing-ontologies)) to visualize the sub/superclass relations, and Protege is one of them (another one certainly from topquadrant's tools I do not have access to), but I can't find any stable tools to visualize "supermodel" in the sense of [this paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-477/paper_37.pdf), which are able to catch other kinds of possible relations, object properties in particular, as defined by domain and range of the properties in the ontology, not actual individuals.

I know, that in general it is not possible because "anything can be said about anything by anyone", but at least explicit domain/range cases could be covered.

**UPDATE**: OntoGraf in Protege 5 beta-17 does not show domain-range out the box (there is no arc type even for this):

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "explicit domain/range cases" and how that differs from what an ontology viewing tool would show you? Because the tools I have used (namely WebVowl and the Protege Ontograph tab) have always shown me properties connected from domain to range.

Comment: Out of the box OntoGraph shows only subclasses and individuals (I have not found any setting, which would enable more), As for WebVOWL, it looks like it qualifies as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Just a note that OntoGraf that ships with Protege 5 does also show domain range relations.

Comment: I am using 5.0.0 beta 17... Hmmm.

Comment: Try closing the tab and reopening it. It looks like it has issues if you make changes to the model while the tab is open. Hopefully resolved once the program leaves beta.

Comment: No, it does not help. Added screenshot to the question. Pls, add an answer (with WebVOWL at least) as for some reason this question is downvoted / flagged to be closed.

Comment: Can you give one of your properties along with its domain and range?

Comment: GML ontology in the screenshot. It has for example geo:contains, with geo:SpatialObject as both domain and range. Or geo:hasGeometry with Feature and Geometry as domain / range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebVowl is an ontology viewing tool that is available at [WebVOWL](http://vowl.visualdataweb.org/webvowl.html) 
It implements the visual notation for owl ontologies.
An alternative is the OntoGraf tool that ships native with Protege.

Comment: WebVOWL does it, thanks! (not sure why people downvote - both the question and the answer)

Comment: Odd that OntoGraf is giving you trouble, in any case I'm glad I could help.